# Create Tickets through Square Connect API?

Tags: square-connect

My company (which does Tutoring services) recently transitioned to Square for their Appointments and POS and I am trying to automate certain tasks. I wanted to know if there was a way to create "Open Tickets" for transactions through the Connect API.

I went through the documentation and couldn't find anything that refers to "tickets". I checked the [seller community](https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/Developer-Discussions/Does-the-connect-API-allow-you-to-generate-a-ticket-on-the/m-p/9108) but wasn't satisfied with the answer from Square since they seemed to not understand what "Tickets" meant. I have provided more details at the end of this post in case someone wasn't sure about "Tickets" here as well.

I believe currently Tickets are only available through the Square POS app (Android/iOS) and not on the Web Dashboard. I would like to be pointed in the right direction in terms of what I might need to look at in order to get access to automatic ticket creation.

For more details, please read on.

In order to clarify what I mean by "tickets", [here](https://squareup.com/help/us/en/article/5337-use-open-tickets-with-square) is Square's page regarding "Open Tickets". They are basically a way to create and save transaction info ahead of time so customers can be charged quicker. The way we use "Open Tickets" is we create tickets for Tutoring sessions every day in the morning and when a customer shows up, all they have to do is look up their ticket and pay. We do this since we expect a lot of traffic every day and we want to streamline the process as much as possible.

Therefore, our admin staff ends up creating 80-100 tickets manually every day! I wanted to know if there was a way to automate this. I already have a running Google Sheets with all appointments data that would be needed in order to create a ticket. I just need to find a way to communicate with ticket creation.

I apologize if this is a long post. I tried to be concise but thorough. Please let me know if there is any detail that I missed. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Open Tickets isn’t currently available for Square’s API. Square's API is only able to track completed transactions at this time.

We are constantly improving the product based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your thoughts with the API team.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that in time these features will get added. Are there any alternatives to doing what I want to do? Although Square Appointments has its own integrated POS system, 'Services' and 'Items' are separate entities and only Items has dashboard views by category. We have a lot of services but we have to manually add the item (which we have basically created by cloning our services one by one) to our appointments checkout in order to get the full Dashboard capabilities from selling Items. Instead of using tickets, can I edit the transaction before charging?

Comment: Since your follow-up question is more in line with our Appointments software, I recommend to file an Appointments ticket through our Support Center (https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact) so that a Appointments Specialists can answer your question. Thank you